# Is there a R function to return a row value based on column?

Tags: r

Is there a R function to return the value for name 2 in score 2? For example, I want Bob's score in the score 2 slot for Joe by getting Bob's score from the third row. Any help would be much appreciated. If this question has already been answered, happy to look at other answers.

| Name | Score | Name 2 | Score 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | 100 | Bob |  |
| Mary | 95 | Joe |  |
| Bob | 60 | Mary |  |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `match` to get the index and use that to return the 'Score'

```
df1$Score2 <- with(df1, Score[match(Name2, Name)])
```

-output

```
> df1
  Name Score Name2 Score2
1  Joe   100   Bob     60
2 Mary    95   Joe    100
3  Bob    60  Mary     95
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Name = c("Joe", "Mary", "Bob"), Score = c(100, 
95, 60), Name2 = c("Bob", "Joe", "Mary")),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: thanks so much! any chance you know how to do this in power BI too?

Comment: @Lynn234 no, i don't use powerBI that much